# Python - Adding space to left side of legend between marker and border

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, rectangles

I am having a problem where the markers are very close to the edge of the legend. I created a rectangle for an empty entry, and also hoping that I could adjust the width so it would add space on the left.

I am trying to add space to the left side of the legend only. Using borderpad adds space to all sides of the legend, which is not something I want to do.

Some of the images here provide some good examples of the problem I am trying to fix: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/filledmarker_demo.html

```
extra = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='w', linewidth=0)

lns = (line1, line2, line3, extra)
labs = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"]
legend = ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc=4, numpoints=1, handlelength=0, handletextpad=1, fontsize=16, shadow=True)
frame = legend.get_frame()
frame.set_facecolor('0.90')
```

Answer (score 1):

To increase space on the left side of the legend only, increase the handlelength parameter. At the moment you have it set to 0.